# AJAX script working with only one of the buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

**What I'm trying to do:** Make Upvote and Downvote buttons, using AJAX to send to a php script that processes it.

**The Problem:** The script only works with one set of buttons. Each item has it's own upvote/downvote button but the script only works with the first item but not the rest.

**HTML**(Each item has it's own div with these button/forms)

```
        <form id="upvote-form">
            <input name="idea_name" type="hidden" value="test">
            <input name="topic_name" type="hidden" value="test">
            <input name="vote" type="hidden" value="up">
            <input name="submit" id="upvote" type="submit" value="">
        </form>
        <form id="downvote-form">
            <input name="idea_name" type="hidden" value="test">
            <input name="topic_name" type="hidden" value="test">
            <input name="vote" type="hidden" value="down">
            <input name="submit" id="downvote" type="submit" value="">
        </form>
```

**AJAX/Javascript**(right now this is just a test script)

```
  $(function () {
    $( "#upvote-form" ).on('submit', function (e) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'scripts/vote.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
          alert(data);
        }
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
  $(function () {
    $( "#downvote-form" ).on('submit', function (e) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'scripts/vote.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          alert('form was submitted');
        }
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have duplicate IDs inside each of the divs. $('#upvote-form') will only select the first item with an id of 'upvote-form' since ids are supposed to be unique. change it to a class instead of an id and it will attach the event handler properly.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
data: $('form').serialize(),
```

to:

```
data: $(this).serialize();
```

You were combining both forms. Since they had duplicate names, the server only picked up the ones from the first form.

You also have duplicate IDs in each set of buttons. Change `id="upvote-form"` to `class="upvote-form"`, and the same for `downvote-form`. And change your jQuery to bind to `$('.upvote-form')` and `$('.downvote-form')`.

I don't know if you really need the IDs on the submit buttons. You should remove them if they're not used, or change them to classes and fix the code that binds them.

Comment: See the other answer. I didn't realize you were repeating these forms. You need to use classes instead of IDs.

Comment: After applying the accepted answer's fix, applying your fix helps to send the correct information through the AJAX to the PHP script.